# How to insert arrray to database - laravel

Tags: laravel, model, insert

when I want to add array to database:

```
$tab = array(
   'name' => Input::get('name'), 
   'user_id' => Auth::id()
); 

Foto::create($tab);
```

**MODEL:**

```
<?php 
   class Foto extends Eloquent { 
       public static function create($name) { 
            returnDB::table('galleries')->insert(array('name' => $name['name'], 'user_id' => $name['user_id'])); 
        } 
    }
```

how should model look?

Comment: Are you using Eloquent? (your model extends from Eloquent?)

Comment: `<?php
class Foto extends Eloquent {
 
  public static function create($name)
     {
         returnDB::table('galleries')->insert(array('name' => $name['name'], 'user_id' => $name['user_id']));
     }

 
}` my model

Comment: Declaration of Foto::create() should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::create(array $attributes)

Answer (score 0):

In the controller (FotoController.php) you can write something like this:

```
class FotoController extends BaseController {

   public function create() {
        $foto= new Foto(
            array(
             /*Field's form*/
             "name" => Input::get("name"), 
             "user_id" => Input::get("user_id"),
            )
        );
        $foto->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. I have this in my VideoController.php: `public function postAddgallery()
 {
  $validator = Validator::make(Input::get(), array('name' => 'required|max:60'));
        
        if ($validator->fails()) {
          Session::flash('validation_errors', $validator->errors());
            return Redirect::to('foto/addgallery');
        }

 }` And on this controller I want to add to database an array: `$tab = array(
   'name' => Input::get('name'), 
   'user_id' => Auth::id()
); `

Comment: This is how I add data into my DB. From the View, E.: You can fit the fields "name" and "user_id" in the form of the View and send it to one route, this route send the data to the FotoController... What do not you understand? :l

Comment: model is good? and validation I should add in create function?